# Bootstrap .tab('show') not working for my code

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

Here is my [Code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dL2uthak/)

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#passive_order_categories').tab('show');
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

<button>Click</button>
<div class="tabs-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#active_order_categories" aria-expanded="true">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#passive_order_categories" aria-expanded="false">Passive</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="active_order_categories" class="tab-pane active">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="passive_order_categories" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can't figure out why is `Bootstrap .tab('show')` not working for my code.

Comment: You should post the code here, instead of the link. And as its simple enough, I've copy it to here and make a snippet, for this time.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I will add the codes myself in the future. Nice to see that Stackoverflow has integrated feature to run the snippets.

Comment: Yes, I was surprised at its power when I'm a beginner on SO, and start to use it very often, just note that it has some limits, e.g: you can't use it to demo `localStorage/sessionStorage` related, or some fake echo for ajax test, it's still good to keep jsfiddle a alternative choice.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From [Bootstrap#tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), what the target to trigger is the `tab` that we clicked to show the contents, not the content itself.

You should give the second tab that links to the `passive_order_categories` an id, or use `ul.nav-tabs li:eq(1)`
to get the second `li` in the list.

Or use  `a[href="#passive_order_categories"]` to get the anchor related to that content page.

Then apply the `.tab('show')` on it, not on `$('#passive_order_categories')`

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    // Find the target tab li (or anchor) that links to the content you want to show.
    $('a[href="#passive_order_categories"]').tab('show');
    //$('ul.nav-tabs li:eq(1)').tab('show');
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button>Click</button>
<div class="tabs-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#active_order_categories" aria-expanded="true">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#passive_order_categories" aria-expanded="false">Passive</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="active_order_categories" class="tab-pane active">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="passive_order_categories" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got confused and considered tab content as tab.

Comment: Thank's god you saved me a lot of time !

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>

 <body>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <button>Click</button>

 <nav>
   <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
   </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
 </div>
   <script>
 $('button').click(function() {
  // Find the target tab li (or anchor) that links to the content you want to show.
  $('a[href="#nav-contact"]').tab('show');
  //$('ul.nav-tabs li:eq(1)').tab('show');
 });
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

With my respect to accepted answer (vote for him), here is bootstrap4 working sample.

Comment: I don't think it was required. There is no difference in the JavaScript (jQuery) code.